# PM2 Script Not Found for bin/www

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

Recently i decided to run my app with pm2 as a service. For me `pm2 start app.mjs` runs the app as a service but it seems pm2 doesn't run my express application correctly. I used express npm to build an app like this:

```
//Imports
import express from "express";

//Setups
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT;

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello world!");
});

//Running server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Also tried `pm2 start ./bin/www` that gives me an `Script not found` error and it seems to be okay with `express-generator` not the express npm alongside an app. App works correctly in dev mode (`node app.mjs`).

**UPDATE**

I solved the problem with help of [Konstantinos Lamogiannis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12565601/konstantinos-lamogiannis). After setup the config file as well as the answer, i changed my `app.mjs` to `app.js` form and changed the `import` style to `const variable = require("");` and it fixed my problem. I don't know why that happened but it seems the `pm2` npm may confilct with new nodejs feature which supports the `import` ES6 syntax.

pm2 log was giving to me this error: unhandledRejection you may have forgotten to catch a Promise rejection !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try creating a file with name: `ecosystem.config.js` in your projects root folder and then add the following code in the file:

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [{
    name: 'yourAppName',
    script: 'bin/www/app.mjs', // the path of the script you want to execute,
    // Options reference: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/
    instances: 1,
    autorestart: true,
    watch: false,
    error_file: 'err.log',
    out_file: 'out.log',
    log_file: 'combined.log',
    time: true,
    env: {
    },
  }],
};
```

In the config above you will notice that in script property its value is bin/www/app.mjs. I assume that you have app.mjs under bin/www directory and placed that value.

Then run `pm2-runtime start ecosystem.config.js`

**EDIT #1**

Assuming that your startup file is in your project's root directory use `script: 'app.mjs'`.

So your final `ecosystem.config.js` will be:

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [{
    name: 'yourAppName',
    script: 'app.mjs', // the path of the script you want to execute,
    // Options reference: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/
    instances: 1,
    autorestart: true,
    watch: false,
    error_file: 'err.log',
    out_file: 'out.log',
    log_file: 'combined.log',
    time: true,
    env: {
    },
  }],
};
```

Try then `pm2-runtime start ecosystem.config.js` from your root's project directory (where app.mjs is located).

Comment: Thank you for answering, but i don't see any directory called bin/www in any folder. As i said my app is created from scratch, i used npm init command to start and then installed the express npm and then set the server, in this case there isn't any directory under bin/www name.

Comment: I have added an update to my answer, check if that works for you

Comment: It runs the app.mjs correctly, but i can't reach my localhost:port from browser yet. Maybe there is a internal error which may cause this situation. Thank you for your concern. I will turn your answer into correct one for this topic if it works btw.

Comment: I can try help you with that one if you open an other topic and pm me the link